# Cannot create new Table with FK in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I'm trying to add a new table to my mysql database. The table consists of only two items, each of which is a foreignKey (further down). However, when migrating the changes to the DB I receive an error message (further down) I know that the problem is in the `HS_Countries` foreignKey as I tested it and it is possible to migrate the table when that key is not present.

I have other tables where I have a `HS_Countries` foreignKey. Thats why I'm quite confused by the problem. The structure of `HS_Countries` is further down and also the structure of the other foreignKey.

I am not sure what I have to change to get the migration to work.

**New table:**

```py
class User_Accumulated_Countries(models.Model):
    iso_code = models.ForeignKey(
        'HS_Countries', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='iso_code')
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        'User_Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product')
```

**console log:**

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: main
Running migrations:
  Applying main.0113_user_accumulated_countries...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 239, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (3780, "Referencing column 'iso_code_id' and referenced column 'iso_code' in foreign key constraint 'main_user_accumulate_iso_code_id_65d73d54_fk_main_hs_c' are incompatible.")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 31, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 231, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 247, in apply_migration
    migration_recorded = True
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 115, in __exit__
    self.execute(sql)
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/Users/5knnbdwm/Python_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 239, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (3780, "Referencing column 'iso_code_id' and referenced column 'iso_code' in foreign key constraint 'main_user_accumulate_iso_code_id_65d73d54_fk_main_hs_c' are incompatible.")
```

**Other foreigKeys:**

```py
class HS_Countries(models.Model):
    iso_code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=2)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    eu = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    fta = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    # ...

class User_Product(models.Model):
    code = models.ForeignKey('HS_Code', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    article_id_own = models.TextField()
    article_id_customer = models.TextField(null=True)
    article_name_own = models.TextField()
    article_name_customer = models.TextField(null=True)
    country_of_origin = models.ForeignKey(
        'HS_Countries', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    accumulated = models.BooleanField(null=True)
```

Comment: Likely the collation of the two fields (the primary key of the `User_Product` and the foreign key of `User_Accumulated_Countries`) is different.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes and no thought about that as well but see the table `User_Accumulated_Countries` doesnt exist yet

Comment: normally before it can add a foreign key constraint (like here) it first constructs the table.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem okay get what you are saying. Have to look into that. Might be cuz I moved the DB service